Error while trying to use the picam2 library: module 'kms' has no attribute 'PixelFormat'
I have been facing an issue. I have a project, where I have to use facial recognition from insightface to detect know people. Hardware-wise, I have been given a Raspberry pi 5 and two picams (v1.3, v2.1). I found out that there is an issue with the picam 2 not being detected by the system on pi5, so I am using the version 1.3. However, the issue I have been facing is the constant error AttributeError: module 'kms' has no attribute 'PixelFormat'.
To troubleshoot it, I reinstalled the picam2 library, verified that I do not have clashing versions, tried using no preview. No matter what I try, the error occurs.
import cv2
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import numpy as np
import pickle
from insightface.app import *
import Custom_Buzzer
from gpiozero import Device
from gpiozero.pins.lgpio import LGPIOFactory
Device.pin_factory = LGPIOFactory()
picam2 = Picamera2(preview=None)
picam2.configure(picam2.create_still_configuration(main={"format": "RGB888", "size": (640, 480)}))
picam2.start()

# Load the known face embeddings
with open("known_faces.pkl", "rb") as f:
    known_face_encodings, known_face_names = pickle.load(f)

# Initialize the FaceAnalysis app
app = FaceAnalysis()
app.prepare(ctx_id=-1, det_size=(640, 640))

buzzer = Custom_Buzzer.create_buzzer(16)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    frame = picam2.capture_array()
    
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Perform face detection
    faces = app.get(rgb_frame)

    for face in faces:
        # Compute the face embedding
        face_embedding = face.normed_embedding

        # Compare against known faces
        distances = np.linalg.norm(np.array(known_face_encodings) - face_embedding, axis=1)
        min_distance_index = np.argmin(distances)
        min_distance = distances[min_distance_index]

        # Set a threshold for the distance to consider it a match
        threshold = 1.0
        if min_distance < threshold:
            name = known_face_names[min_distance_index]
            Custom_Buzzer.initialize_buzzer(buzzer, 2)
        else:
            name = "Unknown"
            Custom_Buzzer.initialize_buzzer(buzzer, 5)


This is not really a solution, as I believe an issue exists with the libraries currently, but I found a workaround, by basically saving short videos with libcamera which turns out to be functional, and then parsing that as input for analysis for the opencv

You said it yourself, this is not really a solution. It should be left as a comment instead

@CésarDebeunne I believe there is currently no solution, so for people that come seeking help in this exact situation, a workaround might be the best they can find, and in that case they should be able to see it more than just a tiny comment, as it might be the only solution available to them until the libraries are fixed
